# Ember: Is there a way to pass a model through a select dropdown?

Tags: ember.js, drop-down-menu

I am creating a dropdown menu which is populated with cities. When a user selects a city from the dropdown, I would like to pass a city model to my "selectChange" action handler. The problem is that the model is always passed as a string:

```
        <select class="{{b}}__select" onchange={{action "selectChange" value=target.value}}>
            {{#each itinerary.cities as |city|}}
                <option value={{city}}>
                    {{city.name}}
                </option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
```

I could pass the id and then fetch the model from that, but if I could just get this working it would be so much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless something changed a lot in Ember in the last versions, its select tag support it's pretty poorly.

I recommend you to take a look at some Ember select addon, like [ember-power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select) or [emberx-select](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select).

I think the first one is the most popular.